# Woocommerc if two products in cart make a set price

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I am trying to add discounts to the total price of the cart when the quantity of the cart is in multiples of 2; I've have some code in place that only allows one quantity of each product and I plan on having 9 products.

Right now the prices are $17/product; if the user adds two products, the total should be $30, and that should reflect at every multiple of 2 quantity (meaning with 3 products, the price is $47, but at 4, it's $60).

Below is my code. For some reason when I have one product in the cart it sets the total to $30.

```
function custom_price_function( $total, $cart ) {
    //if( $cart->cart_contents_count = 2 && $cart->cart_contents_count >= 80 )
    if( $cart->cart_contents_count = 2 )
        $total = 30;
    return $total;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'custom_price_function', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
function calculate_total($total, $cart) {

    if($cart->cart_contents_count == 1){
        return $total;
    }
    $to_discount = 0;
    for($x = 0; $x <= $cart->cart_contents_count; $x ++){
        if($x % 2 === 0){
            $to_discount += 2;
        }

        if($cart->cart_contents_count == $x && $x % 2 === 0){
            $to_discount += 2;
        }
    }

    return $new_price - $to_discount;;
}   
add_filter( 'woocommerce_calculated_total', 'calculate_total', 10, 2 );
```

what we do is calculate base on the total of items in the cart. you can extend this to be more dynamic. but it does what you need for now

Simple test:

```
for($x = 1; $x < 10; $x++ ){
    echo calculate_total(17 * $x, $x) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
17
30
47
62
79
94
111
126
143
```

Comment: thanks, this is awesome. I noticed that when I have products of  2 in the cart it's still short (eg, 2 products = 32, not 30, 4 products = 64, not 60). I tried playing around with it (mainly the `$single_price - 2` if statement, like `$single_price - (2*$cart->cart_contents_count)`), but I couldn't get it right.

Comment: Maybe I overlooked something.. let me checked hehe

Comment: Cool, thank you. How would I make it so it's `17, 30, 47, 60, 77, 90`?

Comment: thanks for the updated code. It seems your removed the `$new_price`code so now it's undeclared.